# How to set the height of two Bootstrap 4 columns to content height when the columns wrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 2 scrollable columns in Bootstrap 4 and they work ok:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column vh-100">
  <div class="row border flex-shrink-0">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="row flex-grow-1 overflow-hidden">
    <div class="col-6 mh-100 overflow-auto">
      Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
      Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
      Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
    </div>
    <div class='col-6 mh-100 overflow-auto'>
      World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>
      World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>
      World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row border flex-shrink-0">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

For mobile, I use `@media` to change `mh-100` and `overflow` and wrap the 2 columns into 1 column like this:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column vh-100">
  <div class="row border flex-shrink-0">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="row flex-grow-1 mh-100 overflow-auto">
    <div class="col-12 overflow-visible">
      Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
      Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
      Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
    </div>
    <div class='col-12 overflow-visible'>
      World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>
      World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>
      World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row border flex-shrink-0">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

This is OK, when scrollbar is visible.

But when there is no scrollbar, both columns have 50% height:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column vh-100">
  <div class="row border flex-shrink-0">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="row flex-grow-1 mh-100 overflow-auto">
    <div class="col-12 overflow-visible">
      Hello
    </div>
    <div class='col-12 overflow-visible'>
      World
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row border flex-shrink-0">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I set the height of the first column to fit the content when there is no scrollbar?

**I don't want to loose the existing functionality.**

I know that the columns will fit the content if I remove `flex-grow-1` from the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use `@media` to add `display: block!important` to the row on mobile:

Now it works with the scrollbar:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column vh-100">
  <div class="row border flex-shrink-0">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="row d-block flex-grow-1 mh-100 overflow-auto">
    <div class="col-12 overflow-visible">
      Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
      Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
      Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
    </div>
    <div class='col-12 overflow-visible'>
      World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>
      World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>
      World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>World<br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row border flex-shrink-0">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

And it works when there is no scrollbar:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column vh-100">
  <div class="row border flex-shrink-0">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="row d-block flex-grow-1 mh-100 overflow-auto">
    <div class="col-12 overflow-visible">
      Hello
    </div>
    <div class='col-12 overflow-visible'>
      World
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row border flex-shrink-0">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```